# Why to use ironruby for Windows UI Automation

Tags: wpf, user-interface, automated-tests, ironruby

I want to automate my test of a windows application (WPF) and I found some articles about doing that with ironruby, however which is the killer reason for writing it with ruby instead of c#.

Answer (score 0):

The killer reason(s) can be:

- Ruby provides some beautiful test frameworks
- Ruby requires less boiler plate code compared to C# so your test code will be shorter
- You can have Ruby programmes involved in writing test code for your C# project

Comment: But aren't there similar test frameworks available for C#, which also help reduce the amount of boiler-plate code you need for testing?